# Laravel UnitTest -> environment variables are totally ignored

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I'm about to run crazy!

I have a simple local Laravel setup on xampp `(not php artisan serve)` with `mysql` which runs fine.
Now I want to setup phpunit. I read the Laravel docs, read tons of blog post and finally discovered YouTube.

I tried to use `.env.testing`, configured vars in `phpunit.xml`, I also tried a different connection block in `config/database.php`

I can do whatever I want, phpunit still takes the DB settings which a active in .env after running the `php artisan config:cache`

Even if I directly pass the `.env.testing` over by running `php artisan test --env=testing`, phpunit still takes the prod DB.

What did I miss to tell phpunit to take another DB in this configuration and don't ignore my env inputs on `.env.testing` or `phpunit.xml`?

.env:

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

.env.testing:

```php
DB_CONNECTION=mysql_testing
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mydb_test
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

phpunit.xml:

```php
<server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
<server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_testing"/>
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value="mydb_test"/>
```

config/database.php:

```php
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
...
]
'mysql_testing' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
...
]
```

I have both DB: `mydb` and `mydb_test`

I've also testet this version:

config/database.php:

```php
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydb'),
...
]
'mysql_testing' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_TEST', 'mydb_test'),
...
]
```

...with `DB_DATABASE_TEST=mydb_test` in my `phpunit.xml` and `.env`

Phpunit still uses the `mydb`

Thanks!

Comment: you also tried "php artisan optimize:clear" ????

Comment: you made my day  incredible; I thought I did everything but yeah, optimize:clear did it. Thank you Marcel!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Marcel Santing](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11479756/marcel-santing)! With all my tries and different approaches, I simply did not run `php artisan optimize:clear`, which made the difference.

Comment: Sometimes two know more than one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if your docker-compose.yml has:

```
- env_file: .env
```

It means that all your .env variables used into Laravel will be shared with container like environment variables. Every time you try to run your tests, the container will use APP_ENV based on .env in your project that probably has "local" by default. It will prevent your phpunit.xml be readed. It was my case...

Answer (score 0):

### it's work for me

in your `TestCase.php` add:

```php
public function __construct(?string $name = null, array $data = [], $dataName = '')
{
    parent::__construct($name, $data, $dataName);
    if(config('app.env') != "testing") {
        \Artisan::call('optimize:clear');
        $this->createApplication();
    }
}
```